# Why can I not drop the constraints with a DROP CONSTRAINT command?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following code in C#:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(webpages_UsersInRolesScripts.dropConstraints);
```

and

```
public const string dropConstraints =
    @"
    USE [DBA];
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    DROP CONSTRAINT [webpages_Roles_UserProfiles_Target];
    DROP CONSTRAINT [webpages_Roles_UserProfiles_Source];
    ";
```

This give me an error message:

```
Message=Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONSTRAINT'.
```

Comment: Also: you should **not** use `USE ...` in your SQL command - the database you're using is already defined in your **connection string**.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to issue the statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_identifier DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_identifier;
```

Comment: I get this error message when there is a full stop in the constraint name